# How to differentiate $O=f(x,t)g(x,t)h(x,t)$ with respect to t?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

For
$$O=f(x,t)g(x,t)h(x,t),
$$
what is $dO \over dt$?

$O$ is a function of $f,g,h$ which are in turn functions of $x,t$. $x$ is not dependent on $t$.

I read that the first two steps to the solution are
$$\frac{dO}{dt}=\frac{dO}{df} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dO}{dg} \frac{dg}{dt} + \frac{dO}{dh} \frac{dh}{dt}=gh\frac{df}{dt}+fh\frac{dg}{dt}+fg\frac{dh}{dt}$$

I have problems understanding these first two steps.

What is the differentiation rule used for the first step? If I cancel the pairs of $df$, $dg$ and $dh$, I get 
$$\frac{dO}{dt}=\frac{dO}{dt}+\frac{dO}{dt}+\frac{dO}{dt}.$$
That doesn't seem to make sennse.

Also, for the second step, what differentiation rule was used to get $$\frac{dO}{df}=gh, \frac{dO}{dg}=fh,\frac{dO}{dh}=fg$$?

Edit: There was some discussion that total time derivatives should not be used. However, the full solution given was 
$$\frac{dO}{dt}=\frac{dO}{df} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{dO}{dg} \frac{dg}{dt} + \frac{dO}{dh} \frac{dh}{dt}$$$$=gh\frac{df}{dt}+fh\frac{dg}{dt}+fg\frac{dh}{dt}$$$$=gh(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \frac{dt}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}) + fh(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} \frac{dt}{dt}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}) + fg(\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} \frac{dt}{dt} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt}) $$ $$=gh \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + fh \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} + fg\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}$$

Comment: You can't cancel $\mathrm{d}f$,$\mathrm{d}g$, $\mathrm{d}h$. And in your case, they are not $\mathrm{d}$-s, but $\partial$-s, because it's partial differentiation. The rules used here are chain rule and product rule.

Comment: Can you update your question by mentioning explicitly what are the variables of $O$? Currently $O$ is a function without variables!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Expanding out f,g,h there will only be x and t left. I think that means the variables of O are x and t?

Comment: @TaeNyFan  You really have to clarify what are the variables of $O$. We can't provide a valuable answer without this piece of information.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It was stated in the textbook that O is a function of fields. A field is a function of x and t. Perhaps it meant O(f,g,h)?

Comment: @Botond Hi, I've added the full solution given on the book. Do you guys mind seeing if there is anything wrong with it? Since you guys are saying that partial and not total time derivatives should be used.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I've added the full solution

Comment: Nvm, I've figured it out. Must be a typo by the writer. df dg dh should indeed be partial derivatives. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the problem in two ways.

**1. Functions composition**

Naming $o : (f,g,h) \mapsto fgh$, you have

$$O(x,t) = o(f(x,t), g(x,t), h(x,t))$$ based on that, you can use chain rule to say

$$\frac{\partial O}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial o}{\partial f}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\frac{\partial o}{\partial g}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\frac{\partial o}{\partial h}.$$

We also have
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial o}{\partial f} &= gh\\
\frac{\partial o}{\partial g} &= fh\\
\frac{\partial o}{\partial h} &= fg
\end{cases}$$

Leading finally to $$\frac{\partial O}{\partial t}=gh\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+fh\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}+fg\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}.$$

this is essentially the solution you mention in your question. Now what I don't like in the provided solution is that $o$ and $O$ are not clearly separated which is confusing.

**2. Product of functions**

There is another way to deal with the problem, writing $O = (fg)h$ and using twice the differentiation of the product of two functions.

Comment: Thank you, but I see that your answer is for $\partial O \over \partial t$. What I really needed was $dO \over dt$. Are those two the same?

Comment: As $O$ has two variables, you need to speak of the partial derivative with regard to $t$ and not of the total derivative.

Comment: It might be that she really needs the $\frac{\mathrm{d}O}{\mathrm{d}t}$, in that case $\frac{\mathrm{d}O}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial O}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial O}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: @mathcounterexample.net Does it mean that $dO \over dt$ is not valid for $O(x,t)$ but if $O=O(f,g,h)$ instead, we can talk about $dO \over dt$ ?

Comment: @Botond Yes I think that was what I need

Comment: @Botond In that case $O$ is not a function of the two variables $x,t$ (as updated in the question) but only of $t$ with $x$ also a function of $t$.

Comment: $O$ is a functon of $x$ and $t$, but if the $2$ variables are related somehow, we can define a new function $\tilde{O}(t):=O(t,x(t))$ and analyse it.

Comment: @Botond I would like to clarify that x is independent of t. x really meant a position coordinate in space which does not move with time.

Comment: @TaeNyFan OK! So $x$ is acting as a constant. Therefore in my answer above, $\frac{\partial O}{\partial t} = \frac{dO}{dt}$.

Comment: In $\frac{\partial O}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial o}{\partial f}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\frac{\partial o}{\partial g}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\frac{\partial o}{\partial h}$, will the pairs of $\partial f$, $\partial g$, $\partial h$ cancel to give $3 \frac{\partial o}{\partial t}$?

Comment: This cancellation won't occur in general.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there was a typo by the writer.

The correct first two steps to the solution should be 
$$\frac{dO}{dt}=\frac{\partial O}{\partial f} \frac{df}{dt} + \frac{\partial O}{\partial g} \frac{dg}{dt} + \frac{\partial O}{\partial h} \frac{dh}{dt}$$$$=gh\frac{df}{dt}+fh\frac{dg}{dt}+fg\frac{dh}{dt}$$